# Justification for feature selection by removing predictors with near zero variance

Tags: regression, feature-selection

I have a large number of variables that I'm trying to reduce, and I've stumbled on Kuhn's (2008) suggestion to eliminate variables with zero or near-zero variance:

> [Near-zero variance means that the] fraction of unique values over the sample size is low (say 10%) [...] [and the] ratio of the frequency of the most prevalent value to the frequency of the second most prevalent value is large (say around 20). If both of these criteria are true and the model in question is susceptible to this type of predictor, it may be advantageous to remove the variable from the model.
>
> -- Kuhn, M., & Johnson, K. (2013). *Applied predictive modeling,* New York, NY: Springer.

This makes sense to me, it's been used in other studies, and it would do exactly what I'm hoping for with my data. However, as far as I can tell, Kuhn doesn't provide any justification (either theoretical or empirical) for using this technique, and I can't find any other literature that supports this.

Does anyone know of other sources that demonstrate why this technique works?

Comment: What *quantitative* criterion do you propose to distinguish "near-zero" from "zero" variance?  Although understanding the motivation behind Kuhn's suggestion, I confess to being extremely sceptical, in light of the fact that what matters is the *relationship* between each explanatory variable and the response variable (after controlling for the other explanatory variables). If tiny changes in one variable consistently are associated with appreciable changes in the response, then surely you would want to keep that variable!

Comment: Zero-variance won't even run in most packages/would crash the model. Removing near-zero-variance predictors would also eliminate dummy variables and other binary predictors. this has 2 refs to alternative procedures http://www.r-bloggers.com/near-zero-variance-predictors-should-we-remove-them/

Comment: @whuber : Right now I'm considering Kuhn's criteria, which are:
- "The fraction of unique values over the sample size is low (say 10 %)."
- "The ratio of the frequency of the most prevalent value to the frequency of the second most prevalent value is large (say around 20)."

I appreciate your skepticism, but couldn't there be cases where I don't want to keep the variable? So, I'm looking at how features of games affect user ratings of those games. If the highest-rated game is the only one to have feature X, isn't there the danger that a PCA model would overestimate the impact of feature X?

Comment: There may be that danger, yes--but eliminating the variable altogether is the wrong way to deal with it (in your hypothetical case) because you would then be removing perhaps the most important explanatory variable you have!

Comment: Could you provide a full reference & perhaps a quote or summary of the recommendation? There's probably some sense in it when building a predictive model, but it has to be understood in a context-specific way. A range of temperatures in a sample from 25ºC to 40ºC might be considered a high variance in enzyme kinetics but a low variance in metallurgy. It comes down to not filling your model up with predictors that you'd expect to have a negligible relationship to the response over the range they take in your sample.

Comment: @Scortchi Sorry for the delay; obviously haven't been here for a while. :) Here's the info:

Near-zero equals: "The fraction of unique values over the sample size is low (say 10%)" and "[t]he ratio of the frequency of the most prevalent value to the frequency of the second most prevalent value is large (say around 20). If both of these criteria are true and the model in question is susceptible to this type of predictor, it may be advantageous to remove the variable from the model."

Kuhn, M., & Johnson, K. (2013). _Applied predictive modeling_ New York, NY: Springer.

Comment: I would have to agree with whuber on this one. I have found some of the most influential predictors in many of my models to be near-zero variance.

Comment: I have found Applied predictive modeling from Kuhn & Johnson to be a bit inconsistent on explanatory variables informativeness. For exemple they shift from PCA to PLS because PCA rely on relations between explanatory variables but not towards the output. However they don't show the same consideration to the relation to the output for other techniques such as removing near-zero variance predictors.

Comment: A good rule of thumb I found during a thought experiment is to consider the perfect explanatory variable : the output itself. Having the output in the explanatory variable should not be interesting for the modelling part. However, in practice, I have found that adding the output to the explanatory variable does not give the perfect model. Quite often that perfect variable is dropped by the pre-processing. So my rule of thumb is to try the preprocessing with the output as an explanatory variable and avoid steps that would drop it.

Answer (score 3):

Based on my experience, I often remove near zero variance predictors (or predictors which have one value only) since they are considered to have less predictive power. In some cases such predictors can also cause numerical problems and cause a model to crash. This can occur either due to division by zero (if a standardization is performed in the data) or due to numerical precision issues. The paper (http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/paper) provides some reasoning though not rigorously proving it in pages 3 and 4.

An example dealing with near zero predictors that I found useful is : https://tgmstat.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/near-zero-variance-predictors/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Predictors with a unique value or with zero variance are constant and therefore will automatically be eliminated by any good regression software.  "Near zero," on the other hand, is utterly meaningless, because internally the variables will be standardized and thus all variances become unity (and are all equal).

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, a zero variance variable is one whose values are all the same constant variable and a near-zero variance (NZV) variable is one where almost all values are constant and only a few have values that differ from that constant. I cannot give a definitive answer, but I think that there is a reasonable logic to the recommendation of removing such variables. (Although I can appreciate the logic, I think there might be a better solution that I give at the end of my answer.)

Let us take for granted that we agree that zero-variance variables are bad, whether or not an algorithm automatically drops them. The question is whether NZV variables are also so bad that they ought to be dropped. Let's leave aside for the moment the nontrivial question of how near-zero is serious to be dropped--I will return to this issue shortly.

Suppose we leave an NZV variable in the analysis and suppose this variable is very near zero. (Again, let's hold off on quantifying how much "very near zero" actually means--just stay with me for the concept.) Many typical machine learning workflows involve splitting an original dataset into several subsets. (Machine learning workflows are relevant here because that is Max Kuhn's context in the book you cited.) For example, we might start with a dataset of 10000 lines. Then we split it into a 70% training set (7000 lines) and a 30% test set (3000 lines). Then to compare and select among multiple models that are being trained, we might employ 10-fold cross-validation on the training set which involves splitting the training set such that there are ten overlapping subsets of 6300 lines each.

With all these splits, it is quite plausible that a variable that has near-zero variance ends up having zero variance in one or more of the 6300-line cross-validation samples. That would be a problem. Some algorithms might crash on such cross-validation subsets. Other algorithms might automatically drop the problematic variable, but that would also be a problem because then the ten cross-validation folds would no longer have identical sets of variables, so the models created would not be comparable.

**Because of these potential problems, it makes sense to identify in advance which variables are so near zero variance that they could end up becoming zero variance with various data splits.**

That said, the question of "how near zero is too near" is challenging as it varies widely across datasets. As several comments have indicated, systematically removing NZV variables based on any criteria risks eliminating some variables that might have a strong relationship with the target outcome. I would suggest to rather run the data anyways even if there are some NZV variables and then dealing with any problems as they might come up. If the scenario I raised above never comes up (that is, no subset of the data ends up with zero variance), then there is no problem. However, if that situation comes up, then one possible solution would be to [stratify the cross-validation folds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratified_sampling) by the NZV variable to ensure that every fold has some of the few minority cases.

**In short, whereas NZV variables are a legitimate concern, there might be better ways for dealing with the problem that do not risk eliminating these potential valuable estimators.**

Comment: I cannot tell what you are writing about, because I don't know what an "NZV variable" is.  When I do regression, internally I first standardize my variables.  Thus, *all* variables either have *the same* unit variance or they are constants.  The former cannot possibly qualify as NZV whereas the latter have *exactly* zero variance.  It would appear, then, that I will never see an NZV in any analysis.  See my comment to a previous answer in this thread.

Comment: @whuber, a near-zero variance (NZV) variable is one where almost all values are constant and only a few have values that differ from that constant. The crucial point of my answer is that in some typical machine learning workflows, such a variable will end up being constant in some subsets of the data. Even if the algorithm removes such a constant variable, that is problematic because then the data splits are no longer identically structured and thus are no longer comparable. I hope the problem is clear now. That said, I concur that deleting them is not necessarily the best solution.

Comment: @whuber I indeed read your previous comments, but I do not think they address the point that I make in my answer. Besides, I'm not sure that all machine learning algorithms handle this issue as smoothly as GLM regression.

Comment: I am editing my answer to define NZV variable as I understand it.

Comment: That edit is likely to help, because it helps us understand that variance is not the essential issue: it's that *there exists a subset of the data in which an NZV is constant and that subset is considered "large" in some sense.*  It would be nice to have some criteria for determining when this is a problem.

Comment: For better or for worse, it seems that "variance" in "near-zero variance" does not mean the same thing as "variance" in statistical variance. Statistical variance is a very precise mathematical formula whereas "near-zero variance" seems to use the word "variance" more colloquially to mean that there are very few different values. (Thus, normalizing to unit statistical variance does not change that fact--there are still very few different values.) Whether we like it or not, "near-zero variance" is a very common and established term and this seems to be what it means, with the confusing meaning.